# Is WPA2 collision-proof?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack, wpa2-psk, collision-attack

I was experimenting with `hashcat` and `aircrack` to test WiFi security.
The WiFi AP is a **WPA2** encrypted network. The tool I used to capture is `bettercap`, which captured multiple **WPA2** handshakes.
The problem is that from those multiple handshakes I get two valid passwords for the same AP.

**Question** is, did I find a WPA2 hash collision or I am getting something wrong?!

Hashes are converted by `hashcat` tools to mode 22000.

**Hashes** from hashcat.potfile:

```
553228db2150902fd563d62c38682260:3a10d53d99a7:facc64a14bb8:Gastzugang:roteskreuz
cdd11e272989dc02fea3e6995b7107cb:3a10d53d99a7:f887f17c94e9:Gastzugang:123456789
```

**UDATE:**
More proof that same WiFi AP handshakes(WPA2) have different passwords!
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not collision proof, but what you're seeing isn't going to be a collision as the chance of getting one is astronomically low.

Comment: So you are imlying that hashcat does a wrong hash calculation in my case ?